# Trigger Jenkins build failure from Android Spoon

Tags: android, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, spoon

I have a Jenkins job that runs Spoon to execute instrumentation tests. One of the tests fails but the this does not cause Jenkins to mark the build as a failure as I would expect.

How would I propagate the test failure to Jenkins?

Here's my build step to launch Spoon:

```
java -jar $SPOON_RUNNER_JAR_PATH \
  --sdk $ANDROID_SDK_DIR \
  --apk testPackages/$testedApkName \
  --test-apk testPackages/$testApkName
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Spoon outputs a file `spoon-output/result.json` that could be parsed for individual test failures. Each test has a JSON field that looks like

```
"status": "PASS"
```

So [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) could be used. A parsing rule would need to be created, something like:

```
error /"status": "FAIL".*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Spoon also stores the junit format test results in `build/spoon/<build_flavour>/<build_type>/junit-reports/*.xml`.

You can then use [JUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) or [xUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) to mark the build as failing according to your need. I prefer xUnit because it allows setting a threshold for allowed failures.